# Кнопки в Notification

Tags: android, java

Мне нужно создавать оповещения с двумя кнопками( Аналог в ВК, когда приходит заявка на добавления в друзья). 
Погуглив, нашла вот что:

```
Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
    .setContentText("Subject")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();
```

Проблема в том, что создавая таким образом, выводится ошибка. Eclipse даже не предлагает использовать **addAction**

Answer (score 3):

Плохо гуглите [@Мария_1](/users/8646/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_1)

Надо делать кастомный layout. Смотрите [пример здесь](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/09/15/create-custom-notification-android-custom-layout/)

`.addAction()` работает только с support package или начиная с какой-то API level.